# Find the volume inside the cylinder and under the sphere

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

Find the volume inside the cylinder  $x^2+y^2=1$ under the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=4$ for $z\geq 0$.

I've seen similar questions here but I don't think they have the right answer. I just want to check that my procedure is right.

Some people who have asked this question intersect the sphere with the cylinder but I believe that would be wrong due to the specifics of the problem. It might seem that I just need to calculate the volume of the upper half sphere on the region in the $XY$ plane in which the cylinder is defined (so the volume would be inside the cylinder). That is, the region: $A=\{(x,y) \ : \ x^2+y^2=1 \}$, so the requested volume would be:

$$ V = \int_{-1}^1 \int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \sqrt{4-(x^2+y^2)} \ dy \ dx$$

In polar coordinates that would be:

$$V = \int_0^{2\pi} \left( \int_0^1 \sqrt{4-r^2} \ r \ dr \right) \ d \theta = \int_0^{2 \pi} - \dfrac{1}{2} \left(\dfrac{2}{3} (4-r^2)^{\frac{3}{2}} |_0^1\right) d \theta $$

$$ = \int_0^{2 \pi} -\dfrac{1}{3} (\sqrt{27}-8) d \theta = (-\sqrt{3} + \frac{8}{3}) \theta |_0^{2 \pi} = (\frac{16}{3}-2\sqrt{3}) \pi $$

Comment: I agree._______